# Why dont .NET return null when requesting cookies that don't exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

If i would use the following code to retrieve a cookie:

```
Request.Cookies.Get("LoremIpsum")
```

and this cookie didn't exist I would then get an empty cookie back instead of null. Why is this?

It caused some problems when i wanted to look into the Response cookie collection aswell as the request cookie collection. If the cookie i wanted didn't exist in the response it would add an empty cookie into the response cookie collection and then return it to me. So the cookie which existed in the request would be replaced by the empty response cookie after the page load.

Really annoying and I'm guessing there must be a reason why .NET don't just return null instead?

Comment: You'll have to ask the .NET designers.  We can't know why they choose to do what they did.

Comment: It's [documented behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ezy11xy2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  It's surprising, to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It caused some problems

It shouldn't, because it is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezy11xy2(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the named cookie does not exist, this method creates a new cookie with that name.

So don't assign it without checking:

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("LoremIpsum");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value))
{
    Response.Cookies["LoremIpsum"] = cookie;
}
```

Alternatively, don't use `Get()`, but use the [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38yh3s7x(v=vs.110).aspx), which does return `null` if the given cookie doesn't exist:

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["LoremIpsum"];
if (cookie != null)
{
    Response.Cookies["LoremIpsum"] = cookie;
}
```

Comment: Actually don't use Get to check, enumerate all cookies instead.

Comment: @Alexei but what if you're interested in the value of a specific cookie?

Comment: With Get you don't know if it is missing or has empty value...

Comment: Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contain("cookiekey") is an option